# If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of same order then which of the following is/are true

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of same order then which of the following is/are true:

> $1)$. $AB$ is invertible iff $BA$ is invertible.
>
> $2)$. $AB$ and $BA$ have same eigen vectors.
>
> $3)$. $A$ and $B$ have same eigen vectors if $AB=BA$.
>
> $4)$. $AB$ and $BA$ have same eigen values iff $AB=BA$.

I'm able to solve only $1$. I don't know how to start solving remaining options. Explain Please.

Comment: Hello and welcome, could you provide the definition of a matrix order?

Comment: The number of rows and columns that a matrix has is called its order or its dimension.

Answer (score 2):

1. **TRUE**. Since $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=\det(BA)$.
2. **FALSE**. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   0&0\\
   1&0
   \end{pmatrix}\ \text{and}\  B=\begin{pmatrix}
   0&0\\
   0&1
   \end{pmatrix}$.
3. **FALSE**. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   1&0\\
   0&1
   \end{pmatrix}$. It commutes with every $B$ and has every vector as an eigenvector.
4. **FALSE.** 
   $AB$ and $BA$ always have the same eigenvalues (so the if and **only if** is false):
   If $v\neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ to some eigenvalue $\lambda\neq 0$ we have $Bv\neq 0$ and $$BA(Bv)=B(ABv)=B\lambda v=\lambda Bv$$
   so $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ to the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $\lambda=0$ we have $\det(AB)=0$ and thus also $\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)=\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)=0$ and $\lambda=0$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$.